# TreeView - OnSelectedNodeChanged not firing for Programmatically Added Nodes

Tags: asp.net, select, treeview

I've been searching, including [similar questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088730/asp-net-2-0-treeview-onselectednodechanged-does-not-fire-in-an-user-control) to no avail. If I click on a node that I've added to a `TreeView`, the `OnSelectedNodeChanged` event does not fire. Even ignoring that, just on a `Page_Load()`, the `SelectedNode` property is null.

My TreeView control is:

```
<asp:TreeView runat="server" ID="TheView" OnTreeNodePopulate="Populate" OnSelectedNodeChanged="SelectNode" />
```

In my code behind, I add one node:

```
TreeNode node = new TreeNode( "Root", "1" );
node.PopulateOnDemand = true;
node.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select;
TheView.Nodes.Add( node );
```

Subordinate nodes are added identically:

```
foreach ( MyMenuItem item in list )
{
    TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode( item.DisplayName, item.Value );

    newNode.PopulateOnDemand = true;
    newNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select;
    node.ChildNodes.Add( newNode );
}
```

Everything shows up in the tree as I would expect, the page reloads when I click a node, but then nothing! What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what this is all about, legacy code and all, but [this post at forums.asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/p/1536112/3730892.aspx) showed me the way. There's a CSSFriendlyAdapter in my CSSMenuAdapter.browser file. Deleting that made it work... and makes the tree view look better, too.

Answer (score 0):

I have a programmatic treeview that I load similarly to the way you load yours.  The SelectedNodeChanged Event fires on mine, but because the selecting a node reloads the page, and therefore the tree, I have to tell the tree which node is selected every time it loads.  I do this by using

```
If Request.PhysicalPath = Server.MapPath(myNode.NavigateUrl) Then
     myNode.Selected = True
End If
```

when the nodes are loaded.  It's a hack, and it's in VB, but maybe it'll point you in the right direction.